# Convert from path list to Flare json format?

Tags: python, json, recursion

I have data in python that looks like this:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 50],
 ['a', 'b', 'd', 100],
 ['a', 'b', 'e', 67],
 ['a', 'g', 'c', 12],
 ['q', 'k', 'c', 11],
 ['q', 'b', 'p', 11]]
```

where each element of the list is a complete hierarchical path, and the last element is the size of the path. To do a visualization in D3, I need the data to be in the flare data format - seen here:

https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/test/data/flare.json

So a short piece would look like this

```
{
 "name": "root",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "a",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "b",
     "children": [
      {"name": "c", "value": 50},
      {"name": "d", "value": 100},
      {"name": "e", "value": 67},
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "g",
     "children": [
      {"name": "c", "value": 12},
     ]
    },
```

and so forth...

From what I've been looking up, I think the solution is recursive, and would use the `json` library on a Python dictionary, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using recursion:

```
 def add_to_flare(n, flare):
     children = flare["children"]

     if len(n) == 2:
         children.append({"name": n[0], "value": n[1]})
     else:
         for c in children:
             if c["name"] == n[0]:
                 add_to_flare(n[1:], c)
                 return

         children.append({"name": n[0], "children": []})
         add_to_flare(n[1:], children[-1])

 flare = {"name": "root", "children": []} 

 for i in data:
     add_to_flare(i, flare)
```

To display it nicely, we can use the `json` library:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(flare, indent=1))

{
 "name": "root", 
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "a", 
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "b", 
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "c", 
       "value": 50
      }, 
      {
       "name": "d", 
       "value": 100
      }, 
      {
       "name": "e", 
       "value": 67
      }
     ]
    }, 
    {
     "name": "g", 
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "c", 
       "value": 12
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  }, 
  {
   "name": "q", 
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "k", 
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "c", 
       "value": 11
      }
     ]
    }, 
    {
     "name": "b", 
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "p", 
       "value": 11
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
master = []
for each in your_list:
    head = master
    for i in range(len(each)):
        names = [e['name'] for e in head]
        if i == len(each) - 2:
            head.append({'name': each[i], 'value': each[i+1]})
            break
        if each[i] in names:
            head = head[names.index(each[i])]['children']
        else:
            head.append({'name': each[i], 'children': []})
            head = head[-1]['children']
```

results:

```
[{'children': [{'children': [{'name': 'c', 'value': 50},
                             {'name': 'd', 'value': 100},
                             {'name': 'e', 'value': 67}],
                'name': 'b'},
               {'children': [{'name': 'c', 'value': 12}], 'name': 'g'}],
  'name': 'a'},
 {'children': [{'children': [{'name': 'c', 'value': 11}], 'name': 'k'},
               {'children': [{'name': 'p', 'value': 11}], 'name': 'b'}],
  'name': 'q'}]
```

Please note that `name` and `children` are flipped in this dictionary since it's unordered. But the resulting structure is the same.

put it in root to get your target:

```
my_dict = {'name':'root', 'children': master}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list of lists is stored in variable `l`, you can do:

```
o = []
for s in l:
    c = o
    for i, n in enumerate(['root'] + s[:-1]):
        for d in c:
            if n == d['name']:
                break
        else:
            c.append({'name': n})
            d = c[-1]
        if i < len(s) - 1:
            if 'children' not in d:
                d['children'] = []
            c = d['children']
        else:
            d['value'] = s[-1]
```

so that `o[0]` becomes:

```
{'children': [{'children': [{'children': [{'name': 'c', 'value': 50},
                                          {'name': 'd', 'value': 100},
                                          {'name': 'e', 'value': 67}],
                             'name': 'b'},
                            {'children': [{'name': 'c', 'value': 12}],
                             'name': 'g'}],
               'name': 'a'},
              {'children': [{'children': [{'name': 'c', 'value': 11}],
                             'name': 'k'},
                            {'children': [{'name': 'p', 'value': 11}],
                             'name': 'b'}],
               'name': 'q'}],
 'name': 'root'}
```